# alu.v:55: syntax: error: Invalid module instantiation and it say "I give up."

Tags: verilog, iverilog

My ALU_1bit is right, and I had test it.

But, my alu has problems. how should I fix it?

> alu.v:55: syntax error
> alu.v:55: error: Invalid module instantiation
> I give up.

`ALU_1bit code`

```
timescale 1ns/1ps

module ALU_1bit(
    input               src1,       //1 bit source 1  (input)
    input               src2,       //1 bit source 2  (input)
    input               Ainvert,    //1 bit A_invert  (input)
    input               Binvert,    //1 bit B_invert  (input)
    input               Cin,        //1 bit carry in  (input)
    input       [2-1:0] operation,  //2 bit operation (input)
    output reg          result,     //1 bit result    (output)
    output reg          cout        //1 bit carry out (output)
    );


reg temp1;
reg temp2;
reg temp3;
reg temp4;
reg temp5;

always@(src1 or src2 or Ainvert or Binvert or Cin or operation)
  begin
  case (Ainvert)
    1'b0:  temp1 = src1;   // 0
    1'b1:  temp1 = ~src1;   // 1
  endcase
  //$display("temp1 %d", temp1);
  case (Binvert)
    1'b0:  temp2 = src2;   // 0
    1'b1:  temp2 = ~src2;   // 1
  endcase
  //$display("temp2 %d", temp2);
  temp3 = temp1 & temp2;
  temp4 = temp1 | temp2;
  {cout, temp5} = temp1 + temp2 + Cin;
  //$display("temp3 %d", temp3);
  //$display("temp4 %d", temp4);
  //$display("temp5 %d", temp5);
  case (operation)
    2'b00:  result = temp3;   // AND
    2'b01:  result = temp4;   // OR
    2'b10:  result = temp5;    // addition
    2'b11:  result = temp5;    // addition
  endcase
end

endmodule
```

---

`alu code`

```
timescale 1ns/1ps

module alu(
    input                   rst_n,         // negative reset            (input)
    input        [32-1:0]   src1,          // 32 bits source 1          (input)
    input        [32-1:0]   src2,          // 32 bits source 2          (input)
    input        [ 4-1:0]   ALU_control,   // 4 bits ALU control input  (input)
    output reg   [32-1:0]   result,        // 32 bits result            (output)
    output reg              zero,          // 1 bit when the output is 0, zero must be set (output)
    output reg              cout,          // 1 bit carry out           (output)
    output reg              overflow       // 1 bit overflow            (output)
    );

wire carryout0,  carryout1, carryout2, carryout3, carryout4, carryout5, carryout6, carryout7, carryout8, carryout9, carryout10, carryout11, carryout12, carryout13, carryout14, carryout15, carryout16, carryout17, carryout18, carryout19, carryout20, carryout21, carryout22, carryout23, carryout24, carryout25, carryout26, carryout27, carryout28, carryout29, carryout30;
ALU_1bit UUT0(src1[0], src2[0], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], ALU_control[2], ALU_control[1:0], result[0], carry0);
ALU_1bit UUT1(src1[1], src2[1], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry0, ALU_control[1:0], result[1], carry1);
ALU_1bit UUT2(src1[2], src2[2], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry1, ALU_control[1:0], result[2], carry2);
ALU_1bit UUT3(src1[3], src2[3], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry2, ALU_control[1:0], result[3], carry3);
ALU_1bit UUT4(src1[4], src2[4], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry3, ALU_control[1:0], result[4], carry4);
ALU_1bit UUT5(src1[5], src2[5], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry4, ALU_control[1:0], result[5], carry5);
ALU_1bit UUT6(src1[6], src2[6], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry5, ALU_control[1:0], result[6], carry6);
ALU_1bit UUT7(src1[7], src2[7], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry6, ALU_control[1:0], result[7], carry7);
ALU_1bit UUT8(src1[8], src2[8], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry7, ALU_control[1:0], result[8], carry8);
ALU_1bit UUT9(src1[9], src2[9], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry8, ALU_control[1:0], result[9], carry9);
ALU_1bit UUT10(src1[10], src2[10], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry9, ALU_control[1:0], result[10], carry10);
ALU_1bit UUT11(src1[11], src2[11], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry10, ALU_control[1:0], result[11], carry11);
ALU_1bit UUT12(src1[12], src2[12], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry11, ALU_control[1:0], result[12], carry12);
ALU_1bit UUT13(src1[13], src2[13], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry12, ALU_control[1:0], result[13], carry13);
ALU_1bit UUT14(src1[14], src2[14], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry13, ALU_control[1:0], result[14], carry14);
ALU_1bit UUT15(src1[15], src2[15], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry14, ALU_control[1:0], result[15], carry15);
ALU_1bit UUT16(src1[16], src2[16], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry15, ALU_control[1:0], result[16], carry16);
ALU_1bit UUT17(src1[17], src2[17], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry16, ALU_control[1:0], result[17], carry17);
ALU_1bit UUT18(src1[18], src2[18], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry17, ALU_control[1:0], result[18], carry18);
ALU_1bit UUT19(src1[19], src2[19], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry18, ALU_control[1:0], result[19], carry19);
ALU_1bit UUT20(src1[20], src2[20], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry19, ALU_control[1:0], result[20], carry20);
ALU_1bit UUT21(src1[21], src2[21], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry20, ALU_control[1:0], result[21], carry21);
ALU_1bit UUT22(src1[22], src2[22], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry21, ALU_control[1:0], result[22], carry22);
ALU_1bit UUT23(src1[23], src2[23], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry22, ALU_control[1:0], result[23], carry23);
ALU_1bit UUT24(src1[24], src2[24], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry23, ALU_control[1:0], result[24], carry24);
ALU_1bit UUT25(src1[25], src2[25], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry24, ALU_control[1:0], result[25], carry25);
ALU_1bit UUT26(src1[26], src2[26], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry25, ALU_control[1:0], result[26], carry26);
ALU_1bit UUT27(src1[27], src2[27], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry26, ALU_control[1:0], result[27], carry27);
ALU_1bit UUT28(src1[28], src2[28], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry27, ALU_control[1:0], result[28], carry28);
ALU_1bit UUT29(src1[29], src2[29], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry28, ALU_control[1:0], result[29], carry29);
ALU_1bit UUT30(src1[30], src2[30], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry29, ALU_control[1:0], result[30], carry30);
ALU_1bit UUT31(src1[31], src2[31], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry30, ALU_control[1:0], result[31], cout);

always@(rst_n)
  zero = ~(result[0]|result[1]|result[2]|result[3]|result[4]|result[5]|result[6]|result[7]|result[8]|result[9]|result[10]|result[11]|result[12]|result[13]|result[14]|result[15]|result[16]|result[17]|result[18]|result[19]|result[20]|result[21]|result[22]|result[23]|result[24]|result[25]|result[26]|result[27]|result[28]|result[29]|result[30]|result[31]);
  overflow = result[31] ^ cout;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get 3 compile errors.

You must not declare `result` and `cout` as `reg` in the `alu` module because you drive them from the module instance outputs.  Just use this:

```
output    [32-1:0]   result,        // 32 bits result            (output)
output               cout,          // 1 bit carry out           (output)
```

Also, you need to add `begin` to your `always` block

```
always@(rst_n) begin
  zero = ~(result[0]|result[1]|result[2]|result[3]|result[4]|result[5]|result[6]|result[7]|result[8]|result[9]|result[10]|result[11]|result[12]|result[13]|result[14]|result[15]|result[16]|result[17]|result[18]|result[19]|result[20]|result[21]|result[22]|result[23]|result[24]|result[25]|result[26]|result[27]|result[28]|result[29]|result[30]|result[31]);
  overflow = result[31] ^ cout;
end
```

---

A simpler way to assign to `zero` in this case is to use the reduction-OR operator:

```
zero = ~(|result);
```